# How to find the cause of the skipped tests in testng

Tags: testng

I have 1000 tests and am using dependsOnMethods. There are times when certain tests get skipped due to failures. 
How do i capture the cause of the skipped tests, meaning can i display the information about which test failure caused the test to get skipped.

Comment: More info? What language, tool, technology, tests, etc.

Comment: I am using testng with java. In testng we have dependsOnMethod and if the dependsOnMethod fails, the test skips

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/6d7MCbiktwI this has same concern as yours. You need to use  ITestResult#getThrowable()

Comment: I've tried this before. On skipping it will just display a message stating that the test skipped due to some failed dependent test. It does not mention the testcase name of the failed test.

Comment: @user3627332 - Can you edit your question and show us what you have tried ? Also make sure you are using the latest released version of TestNG (Its currently `6.13.1`)